# s3 : Objects not deleted after expiring

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

The terraform for a bucket creation is like below

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "a" {
   bucket = "test-logs"
   acl    = "private"

     versioning {
        enabled = false
    }

   lifecycle_rule {
        id      = "log"
        enabled = true

        expiration {
             days = 1
    }
  }
}
```

But the objects are not getting deleted after 1 day, what did I miss?

Comment: I have waited for 2-3 days now.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html - read here that there can be a delay, but its not specified.